# how to fix session variable not defined in route (auth.js) while it is working fine in app.js

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, express-router

I am setting up a new server in the nodeJs. where Do I need to set session such that I can access session in route files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `express` and `express-session` you can access to the session data in any request handler function in `req.session`. For example:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.session);
});
```

For more details refer to https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsession.

Comment: authRoutes.route('/login').get(function(req, res){
  console.log(req.session);
  res.status(200).send("login get :"+req.session.user);
});

authRoutes.route('/login').post(function (req, res) {
  authenticate(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(err, user){
    if (user) {
        console.log(req.session.id);
     }
  });
});
why session ID in both post and get are different ? is there any other document or tuutorial which help to implement session in my webapp? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Install express-session module

```
npm install express-session --save
```

In `index.js` file

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'access_token', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))
```

Import all routes in `index.js`**(entry point)**

```
app.get("/", routes);
```

You can access `session` with `req.session` in your function